# Play framework instantiates module twice (with evolution)

Tags: playframework

I am trying to schedule some periodic job in Play framework, by creating a module and injecting Akka ActorSystem. The code looks like this:

```
import akka.actor._
import javax.inject._

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaGuiceSupport

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import play.api.Logger

class JobModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
  Logger info "Job module created"
  def configure() = {
    bind(classOf[Scheduler]).asEagerSingleton
  }
}

object Scheduler
{
  Logger info "Scheduler object created"
  var ticker = 0
}

class Scheduler @Inject() (val system: ActorSystem)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
{
  import Scheduler._
  Logger info "Scheduler class created"

  system.scheduler.schedule(0.seconds, 1.second) {
    Logger debug s"tick $ticker"
    ticker += 1
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, every time I restart the application with in-memory H2 database, the module gets created twice, once before the DB evolution attempt, and then after the evolution is applied. As a result, I get two instances of the same "singleton" object and two scheduled tasks.
Before evolution:

```
13 21:55:00.791 [info]application: Scheduler class created
13 21:55:00.798 [info]application: Scheduler object created
13 21:55:00.798 [debug]application: tick 0
13 21:55:00.869 [error]application: 

! @7145bjbge - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->
```

and after evolution:

```
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get$lzycompute(EvolutionsModule.scala:53)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get(EvolutionsModule.scala:53)
13 21:55:01.799 [debug]application: tick 1
13 21:55:02.810 [debug]application: tick 2
13 21:55:03.810 [debug]application: tick 3
13 21:55:04.810 [debug]application: tick 4
13 21:55:05.810 [debug]application: tick 5
13 21:55:05.975 [info]application: Job module created
13 21:55:06.025 [info]application: Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
13 21:55:06.026 [info]c.z.h.HikariDataSource: HikariPool-1 - is starting.
13 21:55:06.029 [info]p.a.d.DefaultDBApi: Database [default] connected at jdbc:h2:mem:bnitracker
13 21:55:06.061 [info]a.e.s.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
13 21:55:06.064 [info]application: Scheduler class created
13 21:55:06.067 [info]application: Scheduler object created
13 21:55:06.067 [debug]application: tick 0
13 21:55:06.161 [info]play.api.Play: Application started (Dev)
13 21:55:06.810 [debug]application: tick 6
13 21:55:07.076 [debug]application: tick 1
13 21:55:07.810 [debug]application: tick 7
```

Comment: You will find more info on this topic here: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/6433
It was created by you but maybe some other guys will need this.